# licurl - RTSP over TCP over HTTP

Tags: http, rtsp

I was using rtsp over TCP  c-language sample code (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/rtsp.html) which was implemented with libcurl.

There were some steps - send option , send describe , send setup and play.

But I want to get the rtsp over tcp over "HTTP", it seemed no page or article to teach how to use libcurl to implement.

Could any one provide ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://opensource.apple.com//source/QuickTimeStreamingServer/QuickTimeStreamingServer-412.42/Documentation/RTSP_Over_HTTP.pdf). RTSP over HTTP is just multiplexing the RTSP data over a pair of POST and GET connections. If you are familiar with libcurl it should be easy to implement this technique.